# Moqing EF throws exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test but encountered a strange problem

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void Delete_user_save_via_context()
    {

        var data = new List<admins> 
        { 
            new admins() {id = 1,  login = "test" },

        }.AsQueryable();


        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<admins>>(data);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<admins>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<admins>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<admins>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<admins>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator);

        var mockContext = new Mock<Entities>();
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.admins).Returns(mockSet.Object);  //Here i have Exception


        var userService = new UserService(mockContext.Object);
        userService.Delete("test");

        mockSet.Verify(m => m.Remove(It.IsAny<admins>()),Times.Once);
        mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);

    }
```

This throws exception :

> Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException: Can not
>   instantiate proxy of class:  Could not find a constructor that would
>   match given arguments: System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`

Can somebody help with this ?

Implementation of admin class :

```
public partial class admins
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }   
}
```

Comment: Can you show implementation of admins class?

Comment: I don't think `var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<admins>>(data);` is valid mock creation

Comment: i've used this site : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429

Comment: admins class is a partial one. Is there other files which defines this class?

Comment: You are the man :)  correct vesrion is :
  var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<admins>>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<admins>>(data);
```

Should be:

```
var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<admins>>();
```

Comment: Welcome. You should remember to mark the answer which solved your question as correct.